# custom auth guard not logging in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, guard

Before starting, thank you for your help
I have been working with custom laravel auth guards, but, suddenly, my `student` guard stopped working. Every time I try to login as a student I get redirected to the welcome screen
This is the code of config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'student' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'students'
    ]
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'students' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Student::class
    ]


],
```

And in my StudentController I have the following

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->middleware('auth:student');
}
```

I don't really know why it's not working now (as I said, it worked before). I also tried some kind of debugging using laravel tinker and, every time I login, I get this output

PHPWarning:unlink(C:\Users\Julian\Documents\projects\votaciones\sistema_votaciones_laravel\storage\framework/sessions/PjVK3olshxNkD3CVZzzmCfvAq3uNYvoN5Y6irjt7): No such file or directory in C:\Users\Julian\Documents\projects\votaciones\sistema_votaciones_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php on line 183

And after that it returns me an instance of the Student model but, still don't know what the above output means. I hope you can help me, thanks a lot again.

## EDIT!

I found that the redirecting problem is only happening when I try to login with a document larger than 10 characters
It it's helpful, I'm logging like this: `Auth::guard('student')->loginUsingId($document)`

Comment: I'd put my money on your `session` folder not being writeable by the webserver.

Comment: Something I forgot to say: When I try to login with the admin role, wich is using the default authentication guard, it logins with no problems. That's only happening with the student guard